# Moving the `counter` position over its background (OR moving the background itself)

Tags: html, css

There's a `li` counter set inside purple circles. Circles themselves are perfectly vertically centered over `li` items (List item #...), so their position should **stay** as it is. However, the counter *numbers* are shifted to the bottom of the circle, while they should be in its center (i.e. at the *same* level as `li` text).
I tried adding `padding-bottom` to `ol li::before` to rise the counter a little, but this changes vertical proportion of the *circle itself* (as if i changed its `height`).
When i *delete* `top` and `transform` from the `ol li::before` class, the counter moves up to where i **want** it to be, but then the circles themselves *also* move up and counter is again not vertically centered over the circle.
Is there a way to solve this tricky problem?

```css
ol {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: mycounter;
  font-size: calc(0.5em + 2.3vw);
  padding-left: 2.7em;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

ol li {
  counter-increment: mycounter;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid green;
  
    --size: calc(0.5em + 2.3vw);
  line-height: calc(var(--size) + 0.5em);
}

ol li::before {
  content: counter(mycounter);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 50%;
  
    --size: calc(0.5em + 2.3vw);
  left: calc(-1 * var(--size) - 0.5em);
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid purple;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>List item #1</li>
  <li>List item #2</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add line-heigh to your `:before` element, Increase or decrease it as per your need

```css
ol {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: mycounter;
  font-size: calc(0.5em + 2.3vw);
  padding-left: 2.7em;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

ol li {
  counter-increment: mycounter;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid green;
  
    --size: calc(0.5em + 2.3vw);
  line-height: calc(var(--size) + 0.5em);
}

ol li::before {
  content: counter(mycounter);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 50%;
  
    --size: calc(0.5em + 2.3vw);
  left: calc(-1 * var(--size) - 0.5em);
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
  text-align: center;
line-height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid purple;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>List item #1</li>
  <li>List item #2</li>
</ol>
```